# How to get pixel coordinates from canvas polygon (filled area)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, canvas, coordinates

I am creating an interface that enables user to hightlight **custom area** in map with **overlay canvas polygons**. as in figure. then, I want to get **all filled pixels** from canvas with specified color so that I can transform that pixel values into **geo LAT-LONG** values. I want to create custom database that hold LAT-LONG values ranges with tagged custom known names. It's ok to create overlay canvas polygons by mouse-dragging. But I have a problem in retrieving filled area from canvas as pixel array. I found that

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
var data=image.data;
```

But,it's impossible to iterate all value and cast related R,G,B values and validate with specified color for entire image data. Instead, is there any way to get image data as pixels only for filled area of polygon and let me know other solutions for this purpose if any?   ![enter image description here][1]
Please help me.

Comment: If each polygon is a overlaid canvas, you should be able to use imageData because the none filled are should be the default color

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks, But I have problem in transforming imagedata into pixel array.

Comment: var data=image.data; data is a array of pixel but the format is somewhat weird (R_G_B_A first pixel = data[0]_data[1]_data[2]_data[3] and the second starts from data[4]) http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is reverse processing. You can simply iterate canvas and create index and related RGBA values by following formula and compare with filled color.

```
var index = (x + y * imageData.width) * 4;
```

sample execution is as follow:

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var data = imageData.data;
  var filled=[];
  for(var x=0;x<canvas.width;x++){
  for(var y=0;y<canvas.height;y++){
    var index = (x + y * imageData.width) * 4;

    if(data[index+0]==colorToCheck.R && data[index+1]==colorToCheck.G && data[index+2]==colorToCheck.B && data[index+3]==colorToCheck.A){
        var cx={"X":x,"Y":y}; //
        filled.push(cx);
    }
  }
```