# Get all x, y coordinates of a predefined area within an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

[image]

Please provide the code that will create an overlay of the red outlined area in the image.  Then, the code should return each and every single x and y coordinate contained within said area.

I would then link to cast each point into a comma separated array or list that can be easily checked against.

Using the canvas HTML5 element would be ideal here so that I can reproduce this for 3 additional images.

[Similar question proof of Concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536987/how-to-get-pixel-coordinates-from-canvas-polygon-filled-area)

Comment: You are not asking for help, you are asking to do the work for you..

Comment: I've searched all over the web and there are similar proof of concepts but not a single question like this exactly.  I am going to do the leg work myself but wanted to throw the question out there for JavaScript Guru's...

Answer (score 1):

*Here's a starting plan for you*

**For each bin:**

1. Pick a unique color,
2. Physically put 3 pieces of tape at the bottom-front, top-front & top-back of the bin. This example image has green tape in the appropriate places.

[image]

3. Take a picture of the group of bins,
4. Draw the picture onto the canvas,
5. Use `context.getImageData` to fetch all the pixels on the canvas,
6. Test the pixels in vertical strips until you find the 4 corners of all 3 pieces of tape,
7. You have the coordinates that define this bin,
8. Create a canvas path connecting the coordinates,
9. Once again go through the pixels you fetched in the image and use `context.isPointInPath` to determine which pixels are inside the bin path.
10. Repeat with different unique colors for each bin in the group.

Comment: does context.getImageData get all coordinates in the picture?
Does context.isPointInPath capture those variables?  Then the one last thing I would need to connect the dots (pun intended), is an output of all the coordinates that return true.  Do you have the syntax for that?

Comment: Yes, getImageData gets very pixel's R,G,B,A component. The array has a known order (so you can match pixel color to specific [x,y] coordinates). Yes...but, isPointInPath allows you to test whether each [x,y] is inside or outside your bin path. If you save the [x,y] of all "inside" points then you have what you desire -- an array of all [x,y] points inside the bin. Yes, there is a syntax to create the path that outlines any one of your bins. You use these path commands: beginPath, moveTo, multiple lineTo & closePath. Then test every pixel with isPointInpath. Good luck with your project!